# Active Directory 2008 R2 Identity Management for Unix Default Attriubutes

Tags: linux, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, identity-management

Forgive me if this has already been answered elsewhere but I'm yest to find a definitive answer.

I'm using AD 2008 R2 and have Identity Management for Unix installed adding the Unix Attributes tab to ADUC. My question is:

Is there a way to change the default values that appear when adding a new user/activating the values in the tab?

For example I want all users to have the same home directory and the same login shell and rather than having to set this each time I'd like to make them the default values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching around, it doesn't appear to be possible, I have attacked it in a different manner using PowerShell for updating normal AD accounts to Unix 'enables' accounts.